# jPOS : Field 70 error iso packing?

Tags: iso8583, jpos

Error while using ISORequestListener for listening ISOMessage from a client. Please suggest a suitable solution for this issues 
Channel -  org.jpos.iso.channel.BASE24TCPChannel and 
Packager - org.jpos.iso.packager.BASE24Packager

```
    <receive>

    <iso-exception>

    org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC: Problem unpacking field 70 (java.lang.RuntimeException: Required 3 but just got 2 bytes) unpacking field=70, consumed=52

    org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC: Problem unpacking field 70 (java.lang.RuntimeException: Required 3 but just got 2 bytes) unpacking field=70, consumed=52

    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:265)

    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:420)

    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:923)

    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:691)

    at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:131)

    at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:72)

    </iso-exception>

    --- header ---

    0000 49 53 4F 30 30 36 30 30 30 30 36 30 ISO006000060

    --- data ---

    0000 30 38 30 30 38 32 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 0800822000000000

    0010 30 30 30 30 30 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 0000040000000000

    0020 30 30 30 30 31 30 33 30 31 30 31 34 33 31 30 30 0000103010143100

    0030 30 33 30 33 33 30 030330

    </receive>

    </log>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's an issue with your channel not properly getting the message length. There's probably a trailer (that "03" you see at the end) involved.

Comment: This was an echo request by a client to our server, so the trailer your are talking about is actually 301, Is there a way where I can get to know what channel is being used by the client

Comment: The 'channel' is actually a jPOS name for the class that implements the wire protocol, your client could be using software other than jPOS, what you have to care is about the wire protocol. I believe that _your_ channel implementation is probably expecting some kind of trailer and subtracting '1' from the message length hence the missing byte. I suggest you double-check your channel's `getMessageLength()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I really appreciate it